# list box populating but not working php

Tags: php, forms, combobox

I tried using a code given in a site to populate a bootstrap combo box. I added and changed the code appropriately in a php file and tried to include the file before the form. But the entire form got disappered. When I removed the include php statement it again appears. 
Why and what to do such that the code inserts here and populate the list box and similarly the table consists of two field pincode and place. When pincode populates on the combo the user selects a pincode then the appropriate place in the table should be listed in the next textbox. Thanks for help

```
<?php include 'pincode.php';?>
               <!-- middle column-->
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h5 class="">Enter details of your school</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                   <form data-toggle="validator" role="form">
  <div class="form-group textareawidth has-feedback">
    <label for="address">Enter school address</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" pattern = "^[_A-z0-9]{1,}$" maxlength="150" rows ="3" name = "saddress" id="address" placeholder="Enter address with out pincode" required></textarea>
    <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="help-block with-errors"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group textareawidth">
  <label for="pin">Select list:</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="pin" name ="pin_code">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
   </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group textareawidth">
    <label for="place">Place</label>
    <input type ="text" class="form-control" name = "splace" id="place" required>
    <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="help-block with-errors"></span>
</div>
```

I have included the part of the form here. 
The php file consists of code

```
<?php
$dbcon1=mysqli_connect( "localhost", "root","","simple_login") or die(mysql_error());
mysqli_select_db( $dbcon1,"" ) or die(mysql_error());

$check_place = "SELECT * country FROM pincode";
$run=mysqli_query($dbcon1,$check_place);

while($check_place = mysqli_fetch_array( $run ))
{

    $pin_code = $pincode['pin'];
    $pin_place = $country['place'];

    $pin_block .= '<OPTION value="'.$pim_code.'">'.'</OPTION>';
}
?>
```

Comment: I will remove the option tag and should include the                              <?php echo $pin_block; ?> statement in the HTML part but its not working. First the entire form disappears after adding the include statement

Comment: `$pim_code` typo, undefined variable and using the wrong variable from the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

$check_place = "SELECT * country FROM pincode";

there is error in the mysql statement.

change to

$check_place = "SELECT * FROM pincode";

this will get all rows from the table